# jquery contains() does not work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery contains and it doesn't seem to show up any elements.

HTML

```
  <ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
      <li class="token-input-token-facebook"><p>JavaScript</p></li>
      <li class="token-input-token-facebook"><p>Scheme</p></li>
  </ul>
```

JS

```
 $(".token-input-list-facebook li p:contains('Javascript')");
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cJmxf/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`:contains` is case sensitive](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Try capitalizing the S in "JavaScript".

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cJmxf/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
$("p:contains('JavaScript')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```